# Mysql excludes first parameter when using AND & OR LIKE in same query?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to perform this really simple query.

> links_public 1 = show
>
> links_public 0 = dont show

However, when running the query below it still returns all rows where links_public are set to 0.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM links
 WHERE links_public = '1'
 AND links_description LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_created_by LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_link LIKE '%$filter%'
 ORDER BY links_created DESC
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some () to make priority right.

Comment: The OR is creating a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OR is creating the problem. You need to use () for grouping the condition. You should use:-

```
SELECT *
 FROM links
 WHERE links_public = '1'
 AND (links_description LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_created_by LIKE '%$filter%' OR links_link LIKE '%$filter%' )
 ORDER BY links_created DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using some brackets.

Something like

```
 SELECT *
 FROM links
 WHERE links_public = '1'
 AND (links_description LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_created_by LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_link LIKE '%$filter%')
 ORDER BY links_created DESC
```

The way you have it, it is seen as

```
SELECT *
 FROM links
 WHERE (links_public = '1'
 AND links_description LIKE '%$filter%')
 OR links_created_by LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_link LIKE '%$filter%'
 ORDER BY links_created DESC
```

Have a look at [12.3.1. Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Answer (score 2):

change

```
SELECT *
 FROM links
 WHERE links_public = '1'
 AND links_description LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_created_by LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_link LIKE '%$filter%'
 ORDER BY links_created DESC
```

to

```
SELECT *
 FROM links
 WHERE links_public = '1'
 AND ( links_description LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_created_by LIKE '%$filter%' OR links_link LIKE '%$filter%' )
 ORDER BY links_created DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Place brackets around and then try:

```
SELECT *
 FROM links
 WHERE (links_public = '1')
 AND (links_description LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_created_by LIKE '%$filter%'
 OR links_link LIKE '%$filter%')
 ORDER BY links_created DESC
```

Comment: Its always feel bad when down voted without a comment. Comment please!!